# Different methods for initializing embedding layer weights in Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

There seem to be two ways of initializing embedding layers in Pytorch 1.0 using an uniform distribution.

For example you have an embedding layer:

```
self.in_embed = nn.Embedding(n_vocab, n_embed)
```

And you want to initialize its weights with an uniform distribution. The first way you can get this done is:

```
self.in_embed.weight.data.uniform_(-1, 1)
```

And another one would be:

```
nn.init.uniform_(self.in_embed.weight, -1.0, 1.0)
```

My question is: what is the difference between the first and second initialization form. Do both methods do the same thing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Both are same

```
torch.manual_seed(3)
emb1 = nn.Embedding(5,5)
emb1.weight.data.uniform_(-1, 1)

torch.manual_seed(3)
emb2 = nn.Embedding(5,5)
nn.init.uniform_(emb2.weight, -1.0, 1.0)

assert torch.sum(torch.abs(emb1.weight.data - emb2.weight.data)).numpy() == 0
```

Every tensor has a `uniform_` method which initializes it with the values from the uniform distribution. Also, the `nn.init` module has a method `uniform_` which takes in a tensor and inits it with values from uniform distribution. Both are same expect first one is using the  member function and the second is using a general utility function.

Answer (score 5):

According to my knowledge both forms are identical in effect as [@mujjiga](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55276792/10886420) answers.

In general my preference goes towards the second option because:

1. You have to access `.data` attribute in the manual case.
2. Using `torch.nn.init` is more explicit and readable (a little subjective)
3. Allows others to modify your source code easier (if they were to change initialization scheme to, say, `xavier_uniform`, only the name would have to change).

**Little offtopic:** TBH, I think `torch.nn.init` should be callable on the layer itself as it would help initialize `torch.nn.Sequential` models using simple `model.apply(torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_)`. Furthermore, it might be beneficial for it to initialize `bias` Tensor as well (or use an appropriate argument) for it, but it is what it is.